# Falha na Replicação do PouchDb para o CouchDb

Tags: javascript, pouchdb, couchdb

### Cénario

tenho o seguinte codigo.:

```
['tableA', 'tableB', 'tableC'].forEach(name => {
    let local = new PouchDB(name, { auto_compaction: true })
    let server = new PouchDB(serverUrl + name)

    var filtro = {
      include_docs: true,
      filter: 'replication/by_dispositivo',
      query_params: { 'dispositivo_id': obj.deviceId }
    }
    local.replicate.from(server, filtro).on('complete', report => {
      var sync = local.sync(server, {
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        ...filtro
      })
    })
})
```

Porém a replicação está ocorrendo com sucesso apenas em uma direção (Server => Local), e não recebo nenhum erro.

Ao analisar o trafego na aba `Network`, vejo que o `${serverUrl}/{name}/_revs_diff` está trazendo o resultado esperado.:

```
{"4b0ea507-cd88-4998-baf0-01629b50516b":{"missing":["2-2133d30de8d44ebd958cee2b68726ffb"],"possible_ancestors":["1-39904a7e55b1cb266c840a2acf34fdc2"]}}
```

ou seja, existe uma revisão local pedente de replicação.

### Auditando Replicação

ao auditar o evento `complete` e `error`, não capturo nenhum erro e recebo, e o complete não informa nenhuma irregularidade.

```
['tableA', 'tableB', 'tableC'].forEach(name => {
    let local = new PouchDB(name, { auto_compaction: true })
    let server = new PouchDB(serverUrl + name)

    let filtro = {
      include_docs: true,
      filter: 'replication/by_dispositivo',
      query_params: { 'dispositivo_id': obj.deviceId }
    }
    local.replicate.from(server, filtro).on('complete', report => {
      let sync = local.sync(server, {
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        ...filtro
      })
      sync.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error)
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))
      }).on('complete', (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
      })
      window.setTimeout(function (evt) {
        state.syncProcess[database].cancel()
      }, 15000)
    })
})
```

**Result.json**

```
{
  "push": {
    "ok": true,
    "start_time": "2018-04-06T15:00:42.266Z",
    "docs_read": 0,
    "docs_written": 0,
    "doc_write_failures": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "status": "cancelled",
    "end_time": "2018-04-06T15:00:42.266Z",
    "last_seq": 0
  },
  "pull": {
    "ok": true,
    "start_time": "2018-04-06T15:00:26.422Z",
    "docs_read": 0,
    "docs_written": 0,
    "doc_write_failures": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "last_seq": "17-g1AAAAJDeJyd0EsOgjAQBuAqJj52nkCPILGldCU3UaYzBA3CQl3rTfQmehO9CRZKAiaGiJtpMs18mX8SxtgodpBNdXbSMUKQZDpM4uxwTMxXP2Qwy_N8Fzsh25vGMILIA62QjU8pUrRNCVvGYW4qrCphUgoCfMVd_W2mTQoKaV1JjpWWIUcuu0qbQjp_pBKeUESLH1OlA1PZxTwGudb7EC1dQt5xH6vdrHYvtF6pSZK-4Oov7WG1Z53QUy56UnRK-LJK406-TxIAm8ruDdzts44",
    "status": "cancelled",
    "end_time": "2018-04-06T15:00:41.427Z"
  }
}
```

### Replicação Manual

Agora ao tentar replicar manualmente do `Server` para `Local`

```
['tableA', 'tableB', 'tableC'].forEach(name => {
    let local = new PouchDB(name, { auto_compaction: true })
    let server = new PouchDB(serverUrl + name)

    let filtro = {
      include_docs: true,
      filter: 'replication/by_dispositivo',
      query_params: { 'dispositivo_id': obj.deviceId }
    }
    local.replicate.from(server, filtro).on('complete', report => {
      local.replicate.to(server, filtro).on('complete', report => {
        console.log(report)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(report, null, 2))
        let sync = local.sync(server, {
          live: true,
          retry: true,
          ...filtro
        })
      }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error)
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))
      })
    })
})
```

não recebo nada no `complete`, porém capturo um `erro`, porém mo mesmo não me ajuda em nada.:

**Error.json**

```
{
  "result": {
    "ok": false,
    "start_time": "2018-04-06T15:07:19.105Z",
    "docs_read": 1,
    "docs_written": 0,
    "doc_write_failures": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "status": "aborting",
    "end_time": "2018-04-06T15:07:19.768Z",
    "last_seq": 3
  }
}
```

### Enviando as Alterações Manualmente - Verificando se não há erros no script de Autorização

```
var deviceId = ''
var listaLocal = []
var listaServer = []

getDeviceId().then(response => {
    deviceId = response
    return local.find({ selector: { dispositivo_id: deviceId } })
}).then(response => {
    listaLocal = response.docs
    return server.find({ selector: { dispositivo_id: deviceId } })
}).then(response => {
    listaServer = response.docs

    var tlocal = listaLocal[0]
    var tServer = listaServer[0]

    Object.keys(tlocal).forEach(key => {
      if (key.indexOf("_") !== 0) {
        tServer[key] = tlocal[key]
      }
    })

    return server.talao_para_aceites.put(tServer).then(result => {
      console.log(result)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
      console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))
    })
})
```

O registro remoto foi atualizado, e segue o retorno.:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "id": "4b0ea507-cd88-4998-baf0-01629b50516b",
  "rev": "2-d9363f28e53fdc145610f5ad3f75a043"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonte da Resposta.: [**`Webpack: Promise is not a constructor`**](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-quick-search/issues/81)

O problema era um mal entendido entre o `pouchdb-promise` e o `webpack`.

Como o `PouchDb` está utilizando um `polyfill` para o `Promise`, mesmo quando o ambiente dá suporte ao `ES2016`.

Então toda vez que ele fazia a seguinte atribuição.:

```
var Promise = require('pouchdb-promise')
```

ele estava fazendo a seguinte atribuição.:

```
var lie = require('lie')
var Promise = { 'default': typeof Promise === 'function' ? Promise : lie }
```

ao invés de realizar a seguinte atribuição.:

```
var lie = require('lie')
var Promise = typeof Promise === 'function' ? Promise : lie
```

Uma forma nada elegante de resolver este problema, serie fazer um `replace` em todos os `packages` na `node_modules`.

```
Localizar: var Promise = require('pouchdb-promise')
Substituir: var Promise = require('pouchdb-promise').default
```

Porém isto tornaria inviável o processo de atualizar os pacotes, assim como este erro iria retornar toda vez que o `branch` foi baixado.

Se olhamos a pasta `node_modules\pouchdb-promise\lib`, podemos notar dois arquivos, um `index.es.js` e `index.js`. sendo que é o `index.es.js` que é processado quando o pacote `pouchdb-promise` é requerido.

Então como solução de contorno, bastou adicionar um alias na configuração do `webpack` para o `pouchdb-promise`, de forma que ele lê-se o `index.js` ao invés `index.es.js`.

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'pouchdb-promise$': "pouchdb-promise/lib/index.js"
  }
}
```

como estou a utilizar o `Quasar Framework`, realizei esta alteração no arquivo `quasar.config.js`

```
build: {
  ...
  extendWebpack (cfg) {     
    ...   
    cfg.resolve.alias['pouchdb-promise$'] = 'pouchdb-promise/lib/index.js'    
    ... 
  }
}
```